# How can I capture the height of a DIV's css attribute? For instance 'height'

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I capture the height of a DIV's css attribute? For instance 'height'.  Here is the HTML. I am using the jquery plugin height

```
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">  
<head>  
<meta charset="utf-8">  
<title>The HTML5 Herald</title>  

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js'>     </script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://orlandovisitornetwork.com/wp- includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.6.1'></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>  


<body>  

    <div id="main" class='test'>
    This is just a test
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">  
window.onload=function()
  {
    var height = $("test").height();

          if (height > 0px)
        {
          alert("DIV Height is" + 'height');
        }
  };
</script>
</body>  
</html>
```

And here is the css. Of course this is very simplified version.

```
.test {
height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  jQuery's `.height()` will get an object's height and you are already using that.  If you change your alert to this: `alert("DIV Height is " + height);`, it will display that height.

Comment: looks like you're already getting the height... are you asking how to test whether it's greater that 0px?  `.height()` will return something like '500px', but if it's just a numeric value you need (for comparison purposes), try `.css("height")`

Comment: @TimA - It's the other way around, and there is no element with a `test` tag ?

Comment: If you want the CSS-defined value for its style of `height`, use `.css("height")`, but if you want its current actual height in its context, you should use `.height()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select a class, the selector needs to start with a period, like below. And variables should not be quoted :

```
$(function() {
    var height = $('.test').height();
    if (height > 0) {
          alert("DIV Height is : " + height);
    }
});
```

Comment: @jfriend00 - It does fix the faulty selector atleast ?

Comment: OK, fair enough.  Then, why don't you explain what you changed in your answer rather than make people try to figure it out.  Some words of explanation are usually a good idea.  It looks like you've now changed three things.

Comment: This solution solves two things. 1) The faulty selector and 2) the return type of height is of int, not the actual CSS.

..but yes, an explanation of that would help. :)

Comment: Looks like the comparison I was making with '0px' is what my error was (I am new to JavaScript/jQuery). Along with other syntax errors.  Using adeneo's fucntion is working as I was expecting. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's what `window.getComputedStyle` is for. In your case:

```
var height = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("main")).height
```

(ID is more reliable than class name. You shouldn't use a class name if there's only one of them)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
window.onload=function()
  {
    var height = $("test").height();

      if (height > 0px)
    {
      alert("DIV Height is" + 'height');
    }
  };
</script>
```

Be careful there. The method `height()` returns a number and you're comparing it to `0px`, no quotes, which is not a string nor a number nor a variable, it might evaluate to `null` or `undefined`. Hence, your comparision will never be true and the code in the block will never be executed.

The method is probably working well, you're just making the wrong comparision. Try comparing `height` to a number.